# Understanding the Distinction Between 'Goal' and 'Target' in English

Tags: word-usage, difference, vocabulary, american-english

As a non-native English speaker, I often encounter the words 'goal' and 'target'. While they appear to be used interchangeably in some contexts, I suspect there might be subtle differences in their meanings or usage.

What is the fundamental difference between 'goal' and 'target' in English?

Comment: To me a *goal* is something you *achieve* once, and a *target* is something you're attempting to *stay on* (so eg. the *goal* is to raise a million dollars, and the *target* is to raise $50k daily). I'd also use *goal* over *target* when describing the reason for doing something - eg. *The goal of the initiative is to improve productivity by twenty percent*.

Comment: I don't recognize the above distinction at all. In certain contexts there's a "literal" difference - ***archers*** aim at ***targets***, ***footballers*** aim at ***goals***. But I'm not aware of any *consistent* semantic distinction between the *figurative / metaphoric* usages. Except maybe a tendency for politicians to set *targets* rather than *goals* when they know perfectly well the target is just something to be aimed at, rather than something that's *expected to be achieved*.

Comment: In the sense of a metaphorical 'thing to be aimed at', Oxford Languages regards them as synonyms.

Comment: In one context there's a difference. Targets are often numerical, but they're also often artificial waypoints on the path to a wider goal. The goal of a medical campaign might be to reduce cancer rates, but the target might be to screen 10000 people a year. Achieving the target brings you closer to the goal. But it's not a good question because there are many different senses in which the words are used and it's impossible to be thorough about all of them. I could write a long list of what sports have targets and what have goals, but that may be completely useless to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some senses they mean the same:

> My supervisor has set me a target/goal of fixing 100 bugs this year.

Goals sometimes tend to be less precise, they are sometimes more like "aspirations":

> My goal is to lose weight.

Targets might be more precise, but even here there is a lot of overlap.

> My target is to lose 7kg in six months.

In the football sense, only "goal" is used. But in the archery/shooting sense only "target" is used.